# Drawing new Kinetic JS polygon with click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, kineticjs

I'm trying to trigger the creation of a new Kinetic shape (not a clone) through the click of another. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I can't seem to find an answer. I've tried the following without any luck:

```
var sq1 = new Kinetic.Rect({
    x: 25,
    y: 400,
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    fill: '#000000',
    draggable: true
    });

var $sq1 = sq1

$sq1.on( "click", function() {
  var sq1copy = new Kinetic.Rect({
    x: 45,
    y: 450,
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    fill: '#FFFFFF',
    draggable: true
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've almost got it...just be sure to add the new sq1 to the layer and also `layer.draw`

```js
    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 750,
        height: 750
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);

var sq1 = new Kinetic.Rect({
    x: 25,
    y: 100,
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    fill: '#000000',
    draggable: true
});
layer.add(sq1);
layer.draw();

var $sq1 = sq1
var offset=20;

$sq1.on( "click", function() {
  var sq1copy = new Kinetic.Rect({
    x: 45+offset,
    y: 150+offset,
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    fill: '#FFFFFF',
    draggable: true
    });
    offset+=20;
    layer.add(sq1copy);
    layer.draw();
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}
#container {
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 750px;
  height: 750px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v5.1.0.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```